# Using PHP PDO with phpseclib3

Tags: php, pdo, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib3 to successfully establish a connection to a remote server with ssh2 / public key

```
$key = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents($keyFile), $password);
$ssh2 = new SSH2($host);
if (!$ssh2->login($username, $key)) {
  throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}
```

I am also able to access a database on the remote server using

```
$mysql = 'mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST DATABASE';
$output = $ssh2->exec($mysql . ' -B -e "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE id=23"');
```

Now I wonder if I could use PHP PDO to deal with the database instead of painstakingly handle the output of `$ssh2->exec()`. Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried stuff like

```
shell_exec('ssh -f -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@host');
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname= ...
```

But nothing really which would make use of the existing ssh2 connection.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-secure-connections.html

Comment: PDO has its own way of connecting and securing that connection. You cannot use another connection.

Comment: The shell_exe should work. Do you have your ssh keys sets up? When you run the command manually do you get any errors? Make sure to use the OS user not the db user.

Comment: @JasonK The solution with shell_exec is not really what I am looking for since it would not use the existing connection. It doesn't seems to be possible to use PDO with another connection, as KIKO pointed out.

Comment: This was proposed on the PHP mailing list almost ten years ago: https://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg64596.html In light of that I think the best approach is to use a pure PHP MySQL client. Such an example can be found at https://github.com/amphp/mysql. I mean, even then, you'd prob need to make changes to the MySQL client but modifying PHP may be less intimidating then modifying C / C++